# Error Comunicacion 3-party system

Tags: c#, tcpip

Tengo dos aplicaciones instaladas localmente(PC)! entre ellas se deben comunicar a traves del TCP/IP (port 5800) usando mensajes xml. El problema es que la comunicacion debe ser a traves de un solo puerto (input/output), al iniciar las transacciones obtengo el siguiente error:

Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

¿que podria hacer?

Comment: Mostrarnos el código relevante de las dos aplicaciones para saber cómo se están intentando comunicar.

Comment: Realmente la pregunta es si yo puedo a traves de un mismo puerto TCP/IP(5800) recibir y enviar peticones al mismo tiempo!

Comment: Sí. El error que tienes es porque estableces una nueva conexión en el mismo puerto, abres un socket asociado al mismo puerto, en vez de reusarlo. Pero de poderse, claro que por supuesto que se puede.

Comment: man!! solo eso necesitaba, Mil gracias! voy a revisar como hago la peticion en la implementacion!